# When does a morphism of idempotents induce a bundle morphism over a fixed base?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a Cauchy complete category, and suppose I have a pair of idempotents $e_i: A_i \to A_i$. A morphism of idempotents is given by $f: A_1 \to A_2$ so that $e_1;f = f;e_2$, and a splitting of the idempotents $r_i: A_i \to B_i, s_i:B_i \to A_i$ induces a map in the arrow category $(f,s_1;f;r_2): r_1 \to r_2$. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition which forces the "base morphism" $s_1;f;r_2:B_1 \to B_2$ to be an isomorphism?